# Why doesn't work tag selector with id selector in html5, css3

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my test code</title>
        <style>
            #h1id {color: blue;}
            h1:active {color: red;}
            h3:hover {color: red;}
            .h3class {color: blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="h1id">id test</h1>
        <h3 class="h3class">class test</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

in this code

h3 selector is working but h1 selector isn't working.

Why doesn't h1 selector working? (h1:active {color: red;})

More question.

----Add my code----

1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>my test code</title>
        <style>
            #atag {color: red;}
            a:hover {color: blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" id="atag">a tag test</a>
    </body>
</html>

2.
<style>
  a {color: red;}
  #atag:hover {color: blue;}
</style>

3.
<style>
  a {color: red;}
  a:hover {color: blue;}
</style>

4.
<style>
  #atag {color: red;}
  #atag:hover {color: blue;}
</style>
```

2, 3, 4 work very well in chrome, explorer

1 doesn't work.

Pseudo-class :hover or :active

Please let me know the reason.

Comment: it's all about specificity, ID is more specific than the other selector (inckuding the active one) so it will win and his style will always get applied

Comment: how about class selector?
in style.
a {color: red;}
.atag:hover {color: blue;}
it work well.
and 
.atag {color: red;}
a:hover {color: blue;}
it also work well.

Comment: (a:hover) < (.atag:hover) priority.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer, it doesn't work because an `<h1>` element, by itself, can never be active.

Long answer, quoting directly from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

- The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.

  /* Selects any `<a>` that is being activated */

  a:active {
    color: red;
  }

The :active pseudo-class is commonly used on `<a>` and `<button>` elements. Other common targets of this pseudo-class include elements that contain an activated element, and form elements that are being activated through their associated `<label>`.

Comment: If h1 replace to #h1id, it work.

Comment: If you use the id selector and tag selector together, the tag selector does not work.

Comment: Your original question was why doesn't it work using a selector for the element. My answer is still valid. If it is working for you when using an ID instead of the element, make sure you test across all browsers before you say that it works.

Comment: Can you please answer in my more question?

Comment: **Plain wrong**. An `<h1>` element **can** be active.